# Dependency rule tried to blank out primary key in SQLAlchemy, when foreign key constraint is part of composite primary key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following model definitions

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(200))


class FooCycle(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foocycle'

    foo_id = Column(
        String(50),
        ForeignKey('foo.id'),
        primary_key=True
    )
    some_number = Column(
        Integer,
        primary_key=True,
    )

    foo = relationship("Foo", backref="cycles")
```

and the following test case

```
class HierarchicModelTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_create_data_via_orm_save_twice(self):
        # get_session is a convenience wrapper to access a scoped session object
        s = get_session()

        def create_foo():
            foo = Foo(id="12345", name="fancy foo")
            foo.cycles = [FooCycle(some_number=1)]

            return foo

        # initially create foo
        foo = create_foo()
        s.add(foo)
        s.flush()

        # recreating foo, using merge to update into database
        foo = create_foo()
        s.merge(foo)

        # raises Exception: Dependency rule tried to blank-out primary key
        # column 'foocycle.foo_id' on instance '<FooCycle at 0x32e6b10>'
        s.flush()
```

The test fails with a neat little stack trace and the final assertion error, telling me that the "Dependency rule tried to blank-out primary key column 'foocycle.foo_id". I'm assuming SQLAlchemy cannot, or doesn't want to calculate the value for foo_id on FooCycle itself. I can explicitly set this value myself in `create_foo`:

```
def create_foo():
    foo = Foo(id="12345", name="fancy foo")
    foo.cycles = [FooCycle(some_number=1, foo_id="12345")]

    return foo
```

But, due to conciseness, architectural considerations and admittedly personal pride I don't want to. Is there a simple way to get SQLAlchemy to resolve this issue. I haven't quite grasped the purpose of the dependency rule. Any pointers/information on that issue?

Stack Trace:

```
# Test 1 of 7:
# test_core.HierarchicModelTest.test_create_data_via_orm_save_twice
===============
HierarchicModelTest: test_create_data_via_orm_save_twice (tests.test_core.HierarchicModelTest)
Failed test "test_create_data_via_orm_save_twice (tests.test_core.HierarchicModelTest)"! Reason: Dependency rule tried to blank-out primary key column 'foocycle.foo_id' on instance '<FooCycle at 0x39cda10>'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/backend/tests/test_core.py", line 115, in test_create_data_via_orm_save_twice
    s.flush()
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 149, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1879, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1997, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 57, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1961, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 370, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 479, in execute
    self.dependency_processor.process_saves(uow, states)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/dependency.py", line 552, in process_saves
    uowcommit, False)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/dependency.py", line 569, in _synchronize
    sync.clear(dest, self.mapper, self.prop.synchronize_pairs)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/sync.py", line 53, in clear
    (r, orm_util.state_str(dest))
AssertionError: Dependency rule tried to blank-out primary key column 'foocycle.foo_id' on instance '<FooCycle at 0x39cda10>'
```

Comment: I do not think this is a problem with the SA not being able to handle `foo_id`. In fact, it is one of the great points that SA indeed is able to do this. I believe the problem is that during the `merge` SA delete the first instance of `FooCycle` and inserts the new one. Deleting the first one is the problem, because it does not delete its row, but only tries to remove the relationship. So you need to configure proper [`cascade`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.cascade) rule for your relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @van Could you please tell us what the *proper* cascade rule would be in this case (preferably as an answer as I guess this could be too much to fit into a comment)? You say that *it does not delete its row, but only tries to remove the relationship*; but if row gets deleted then we get a new instance of `FooCycle` every time. Is there a way to have SA update already existing rows/instances of `FooCycle` instead?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: SA will not automatically update existing rows/instances. You should write a code to first search for the relationship, and *merge* data from new instance into the existing one.

Comment: I asked similar question on SQLAlchemy newsgroup – [Dependency rule tried to blank-out primary key column when trying to update using association proxy](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/-xnphvsklZM) – with interesting in-depth look from SQLAlchemy's author Mike Bayer.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Based on the comment by van I was able to work out a solution. The default relationship cascade is `"save-update, merge"`. I had to set this to `"save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan"`.

Adding `delete` by itself did not change the behavior, `delete-orphan` was necessary.

Adding only `delete-orphan` made a deletion testcase fail, with the "dependency rule" assertion error, mentioned in the question:

```
class HierarchicModelTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_delete_parent_object(self):
        foo = Foo(**foo_data).save()
        self.assertEqual(Foo.query.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(FooCycle.query.count(), 1)

        s = get_session()
        s.delete(foo)
        s.flush()

        self.assertEqual(Foo.query.count(), 0)
        self.assertEqual(FooCycle.query.count(), 0)
```

--

```
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/backend/tests/test_core.py", line 128, in test_delete_parent_object
     s.flush()
  [...]
  AssertionError: Dependency rule tried to blank-out primary key column 'foocycle.foo_id' on instance '<FooCycle at 0x37a1710>'
```

From the SQLAlchemy docs:

> `delete-orphan` cascade adds behavior to the `delete` cascade, such that a child object will be marked for deletion when it is de-associated from the parent, not just when the parent is marked for deletion.

So, the correct definition of the FooCycle Model is

```
class FooCycle(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foocycle'

    foo_id = Column(
        String(50),
        ForeignKey('foo.id'),
        primary_key=True
    )
    some_number = Column(
        Integer,
        primary_key=True,
    )

    foo = relationship("Foo",
                       backref=backref("cycles",
                                        cascade="save-update, merge, "
                                                "delete, delete-orphan"))
```

Comment: However using `delete-orphan` results in already existing instances of `FooCycle` being deleted instead of updated. If identity of `FooCycle` is important (for instance when we want to version it by keeping history of all historic values) then this solution can't be used.

Comment: @room2web: is there a reason why you don't simply put `cascade="all, delete-orphan"` instead of `cascade="save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan"`?

Comment: This worked for me but I had to set that cascade rule on the parent model, not the child one. In my case, I was trying to remove a child object from a list of rows