# Delete all in a Many to Many secondary table association in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have following models and associations:

```
class CartProductsAssociation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cart_products_association'
    cart_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('carts.id',ondelete='CASCADE'),primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.id',ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer)

    product = db.relationship("Product", backref="cart_associations", cascade="all,delete",passive_deletes=True)
    cart = db.relationship("Cart", backref="product_associations",cascade="all,delete",passive_deletes=True)


class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    img_path = db.Column(db.String)

    price = db.Column(db.Float, default=0.0)

    product_categories = db.relationship(
        "ProductCategory",
        secondary=product_product_categories,
        back_populates="products")

    carts = db.relationship("Product", secondary="cart_products_association",passive_deletes=True,cascade="all,delete" )

class Cart(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'carts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    branch_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('branch.id'))
    branch = db.relationship("Branch", back_populates="carts")

    page_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pages.id'))
    page = db.relationship("Page", back_populates="carts")


    shopper_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('shoppers.fb_user_id'))
    shopper = db.relationship(
        "Shopper",
        back_populates="carts")

    products = db.relationship("Product", secondary="cart_products_association")
    cart_status = db.Column(db.Enum('user_unconfirmed','user_confirmed','client_unconfirmed','client_confirmed', name='cart_status'), default='user_unconfirmed')
```

When I am trying to delete a product I am getting following error:
AssertionError

```
AssertionError: Dependency rule tried to blank-out primary key column 'cart_products_association.cart_id' on instance '<CartProductsAssociation at 0x7f5fd41721d0>'
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: @IljaEverilä man you should really stop to mark every question as duplicate. Just insane.

Comment: @anvd Why? First of all you're exaggerating, though in this particular case the dupe target was poorly chosen – good thing it takes more than 1 to close as dupe; on the other hand the question lacks a [mcve] and has obvious errors (`carts = db.relationship("Product", ...)` for example). The back references created by `CartProductsAssociation` have default cascading behaviour, which is to set `product_id` and `cart_id` to NULL, if a related `Product` or `Cart` is removed. Haven't verified, but that is more than likely the cause.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699651/dependency-rule-tried-to-blank-out-primary-key-in-sqlalchemy-when-foreign-key-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it solved the problem:

```
 product = models.Product.query.get(product_id)

 for ass in product.cart_associations:

    db.session.delete(ass)

db.session.delete(product)
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 5):

The error is caused by back references *cart_associations* and *product_associations* created by `CartProductsAssociation`. Since they don't have explicit [cascades](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html) set, they have the default `save-update, merge`, and without [`delete`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html#delete) the

> default behavior is to instead de-associate ... by setting their foreign key reference to NULL.

Due to this when a `Product` is up for deletion SQLAlchemy will first fetch the related `CartProductsAssociation` objects and try to set the primary key to NULL.

It seems that originally there has been an attempt to use `passive_deletes=True` with `ondelete='CASCADE'`, but the passive deletes have ended up on the wrong side of the relationship pair. This should produce a warning:

> `sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py:1790: SAWarning: On CartProductsAssociation.product, 'passive_deletes' is normally configured on one-to-many, one-to-one, many-to-many relationships only.`

If the relationships are configured as

```
class CartProductsAssociation(db.Model):
    ...
    product = db.relationship(
        "Product", backref=db.backref("cart_associations",
                                      cascade="all",
                                      passive_deletes=True))
    cart = db.relationship(
        "Cart", backref=db.backref("product_associations",
                                   cascade="all",
                                   passive_deletes=True))
```

instead, then when a `Product` instance that *has not* loaded its related `CartProductsAssociation` objects is deleted, SQLAlchemy will let the DB handle cascading. Note that the SQLAlchemy `delete` cascade is also necessary, or the error will come back if a `Product` instance that *has* loaded its related association objects is deleted. `passive_deletes="all"` can also be used, if there are some special triggers or such in place in the DB that must be allowed to fire.

When deleting a `Product` that has loaded both *carts* and *cart_associations* the situation is even more complicated, because both [association object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) pattern and a [many to many](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) relationship are in use, and the 2 relationships do not coordinate changes together – see the warning in ["Association Object"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object). You might want to consider either making the other relationship [viewonly](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.viewonly), or use the [association proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) extension across the association object relationship:

```
class Product:
    ...
    carts = association_proxy(
        'cart_associations', 'cart',
        creator=lambda cart: CartProductsAssociation(cart=cart))
```

Finally, the `delete` cascade in `Product.carts` is a bit odd, though may be as designed, and will delete the related `Cart` objects along with the `Product` if they have been loaded, and additionally removes rows from the secondary table. On the other hand that relationship has passive deletes also, so the `Cart` objects are *not* deleted if not loaded when the `Product` is deleted, which would seem to conflict with the SQLAlchemy cascade.